# Why does pressing "0" make the cursor move to the first character of the line in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I usually use `^` go to the right, also to move for the extreme right `$`. So what I wanted to ask is how to move to extreme right with in terms of numbers (like pressing `0` makes you go left, assume if pressing 1, which of course isn't the key to go right), how am I to do it?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question.

Comment: @romainl see if you can understand it now.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I understand your Q, I would answer that all the numbers from 1-9 are used to specify a count to a command to make vim do perform that command several times. E.g. `4dd` deletes 4 lines. If you mapped `4` to do the same as `$` (to avoid needing to hold the shift key) then you would not be able to use `4dd` any more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just what `:help 0` does:

```
0           To the first character of the line.  |exclusive|
            motion.
```

This is a very common need so it got its own dedicated command.

If you want to move the cursor to an arbitrary column, then you must use `:help |`:

```
|           To screen column [count] in the current line.
            |exclusive| motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe.
```

For example, to move the cursor to column 3:

```
3|
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that.